# Android background task for UI

Tags: android, multithreading, bitmap, executorservice, android-gpuimageview

I'm developing an app under Android which handles bitmap and apply GPU filters on a bitmap. As it can be slow, I have decided to set a "default image", like a fake picture, which is displayed until the picture I want to filtered is done.

Prior to this, I was expecting the bitmap to be modified before being displayed, but it's not offering a nice user experience.

The issue is that I have a warning at system level saying :

```
System.err﹕ android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I have seen a few threads which indicate that I have to use the `runOnUiThread`, but I do not know how to make it work.. here is the code of my apps

The activity `FilterActivity`, receives an URI which contains a path to a file. The `FilterPreview` method is handling the class who will manage to queue the action I want to do.

```
public class FiltersActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filters);

        mFiltersView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.filters_place_holder);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mFiltersView.getLayoutParams();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mSnapShotUri = intent.getData();
        getBitmapFromURI(mSnapShotUri);
        ....

    private void getBitmapFromURI(Uri uri) {
        try {
            mSnapShot = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "File not found");
        }
        finally {
            mPreviewBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, PreviewSizeWidth, PreviewSizeHeight, false);
            FiltersPreview();
        }
    }

    private void FiltersPreview() {

        boolean mPreview = true;
        mFiltersView.setAdapter(new CameraImageFiltersAdapter(this, mSnapShot, mPreviewBitmap, mPreview));
        mFiltersView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                CameraFiltersFactory effect = (CameraFiltersFactory) v.findViewById(R.id.filteredImage).getTag();
                effect.save(new GPUImage.OnPictureSavedListener() {

                   @Override public void onPictureSaved(Uri uri) {

                        Intent previewIntent = new Intent(FiltersActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
                        previewIntent.setData(uri);
                        startActivityForResult(previewIntent, 0);

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

In my app, the part below is slowing down the UI, as I do not use a background task/thread to update the UI.

```
        mFiltersView.setAdapter(new CameraImageFiltersAdapter(this, mSnapShot, mPreviewBitmap, mPreview));
```

`CameraImageFiltersAdapter` class (`stub_id` is the fake image displayed during the process of applying filters)

```
public CameraImageFiltersAdapter(Context c, Bitmap original, Bitmap current, boolean isPreview) {
        ....
        mExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView filteredImage;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_filter, null);
            filteredImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.filteredImage);
            filteredImage.setImageResource(stub_id);
            queueFiltered(filteredImage, position);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private void queueFiltered(ImageView imageView, int position) {
        CameraFiltersFactory holder = new CameraFiltersFactory(mContext, imageView);
        mExecutorService.submit(new FilterLoader(holder, position));

    }

    class FilterLoader implements Runnable {
        CameraFiltersFactory FilterToLoad;
        int FilterPosition;

        FilterLoader(CameraFiltersFactory FilterToLoad, int pos) {
            this.FilterToLoad = FilterToLoad;
            this.FilterPosition = pos;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                FilterToLoad.setResources(mOriginalBitmap, mCurrentBitmap, mFilterIds[FilterPosition], mPreview);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can not make changes to views in your ThreadPool's threads, use a main thread handler to post a message and handle it in main thread. Or using AsyncTask like this [Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

pass the activity as a parameter for the adapter and then call:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //change the image here
                        }
                    });
```